# Unable to pass username & password in jaxws

Tags: web-services, soap

I'm trying to call a webservice using username/pwd using the below client but I don't see the username/password being set in the headers

Client code

```
AttachmentWSImplService service = new AttachmentWSImplService();
        AttachmentWS aws = service.getAttachmentWS();
        BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) aws;
        SOAPBinding sopadBinding = (SOAPBinding) bindingProvider.getBinding();
        sopadBinding.setMTOMEnabled(true);

        bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(bindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,"p3xferdt");
        bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(bindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,"92mnGg1Cb14D9hVhG1W5fZra4UI=");
```

Server code

```
    SOAPMessageContext ctx = (SOAPMessageContext) wsCtx
            .getMessageContext();
    java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<java.lang.String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) ctx
            .get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
    if (headers.keySet() != null && !headers.keySet().isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<String> keys = headers.keySet().iterator();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            logger.info("HeaderKey->" + key);
            logger.info("Header values->" + headers.get(key));
            // getting Basic Authentication
            String tmpusername = getUsernameFromAuthentication(key,
                    headers.get(key).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks ok to me, should work fine.

Anyways try accessing Request Header by

```
Headers headers = ex.getRequestHeaders();
List<String> ulist = headers.get(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY);
List<String> plist = headers.get(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY);
```

PS: Remember USERNAME_PROPERTY is static string from BindingProvider interface, can be accessed in Static way. (Coding standards :))